# What is the quickest way to update Table Column from another column in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in Oracle, a million rows and multiple columns each: TABLE_1 (columns: A, B, C) and TABLE_2 (columns: D, E, F).
Columns B and C from table 1 contain same key data as columns E and F from table 2. Based on those keys I need to update column A in table 1 with values from column D from table 2.
The code I am using:

```
update TABLE_1
set TABLE_1.B = (select D from TABLE_2
where TABLE_1.C = TABLE_2.E
and TABLE_1.D = TABLE_2.F
fetch first 1 rows only)
GO
```

But this code takes too long (hours) to execute an there are one million rows in each table.

I have tried adding concatenate columns to each table, but it's still the same, code is too slow.

```
update TABLE_1
set TABLE_1.A = (select D from TABLE_2
where TABLE_1.concat_B&C = TABLE_2.concate_E&F)
GO
```

Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: As a side Note : those `GO` keywords don't belong to Oracle DB.

Comment: could you please clarify if you have any indexes on the involved tables?

Comment: I recommend you to use `create table ... as`  rather (eg. recreating a new table) unless it doesn't violate your business rule.

Comment: @Sergey no indexes as far as I know.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I would prefer not to recreate the table. But even when I try I get a memory error (ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 8192 in tablespace)

Comment: That error, which is specific to your database, tells that you have not enough space provided. You might try to compress the non-compressed tables starting from the ones with low capacity and go on with the ones with high capacity if you have no option to add some extra datafile(s).

Answer (score 1):

You want to update every row in table_1. For this update you look up rows in table_2, and if you find more than one match, you pick one of the matching rows arbitararily.

For this to work efficiently you need an index that helps you find the rows in table_2 instantly. There are two columns that you look at. If one is more selectiv than the other (i.e. for one column there are usually less rows in table_2 than for the other column), place this column first in the index. You can even make the index covering by including the column D, which is not needed to find the row, but is a value you use. With a covering index, the DBMS doesn't have to read the table, as all the information it needs is already in the index.

```
create index idx on table_2 (e, f, d);
```

This is about as fast as it gets. But with more than one CPU, you can still speed this up by parallelizing the update. For instance:

```
update /*+parallel(4)*/ table_1 ...
```

Comment: Code would look something like this?  ```create index idx on table_2 (f, d); select A from TABLE_1 where idx=concat_B&C;```

Comment: @Elmar Do not concatenate columns, just use your first query and add a composite index on multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO TABLE_1 dst
USING TABLE_2 src
ON (dst.B = src.E AND dst.C = src.F)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET A = src.D;
```

Or, if you will get multiple rows that match:

```sql
MERGE INTO TABLE_1 dst
USING (
  SELECT d, e, f,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e, f ORDER BY something) AS rn
  FROM   TABLE_2
) src
ON (dst.B = src.E AND dst.C = src.F AND src.rn = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET A = src.D;
```

You can also add composite indexes so that the queries can use the index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX table_1__b_c__idx ON table_1 (b, c);
CREATE INDEX table_2__e_f_d__idx ON table_2 (e, f, d);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Li9XiKX8)

Comment: Tried the second code (with ROW_NUMBER()) and I am getting an error: ```ORA-00923: FROM keyboard not found where expected```

Comment: @Elmar It works for me [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Li9XiKX8)